# Target table not allowing itself to be derived from a query on itself

Tags: mysql

I get the an error for the below MySQL.

`Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'songlist' for update in FROM clause`

I think I need to be using inner join, but can't seem to make it work with my WHERE clause nested in the select statement. Any ideas?

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE samdb.songlist 
SET 
    songlist.xfade = (SELECT 
            t.xfade
        FROM
            tmpsonglist AS t,
            songlist AS s
        WHERE
            t.album = s.album)
WHERE
    filename LIKE '%201501.mp3';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

The desired outcome is to update column values of `xfade` in `songlist` with `tmpsonglist`, as long as the `filename` field ends in `201501.mp3` (based on a common `album` field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE samdb.songlist AS s
    INNER JOIN samdb.tmpsonglist AS t
        ON t.album = s.album
SET 
    s.xfade = t.xfade
WHERE
    s.filename LIKE '%201501.mp3';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

You do not need a nested query because the join involves the table to be updated. You can simply use an inner join and update only the required table by using the reference.

Comment: Ah great, that seems to have worked. I edited the WHERE line to be unambiguous and it worked (MySQL's terminology, not mine!)

Comment: I too figured that problem, and corrected my answer. If it helped, please accept the answer. Cheers :)